# The prhase " I would like a dragon to heat my pool"

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context, idioms

I was watching an american drama, and one of characters in it said

"I would like a dragon to heat my pool"

I just want to know the exact meaning of it. The context of this sentence is as below.

(Someone leaked a sensitive information of A and B)

A : If there is a leak I will find it, and Jason will get what he deserves

B: When you do find Jason, if it pleases you, I would like to conduct the interrogation.

**A: I would like a dragon to heat my pool**

Comment: Hello, KSM. As @MetaEd has said, interpretation requests are out of scope and may be removed. This is just a quirky nonce expression, not standard usage / idiom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context you cite, the citing of something impossible to have as the thing A wants is a sarcastic way of saying that B’s request isn’t likely to be granted.

It’s an [adynaton](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adynaton) along the lines of [*when pigs fly*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/When_pigs_fly).

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted.

Comment: Perhaps a better comparison would be to “People in Hell want ice-water.”